# Export Massive table to Excel ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: excel, epplus

I'm getting a List form the DB and i have some data that needs to be written in Excel but i need to do some value changing first. So i'm using a nested for statement to iterate in the values and change those i need it, but i need to speed up the process. Takes a long time to do this, how can i optimize it? I thought of converting it to a foreach statement.

```
private static void GenerateSheetRows<T>( ExcelWorksheet wsSheet, List<T> data )
    {
        PropertyInfo [ ] props = typeof ( T ).GetProperties ( );

        int startRow = 2;
        int finalColumn = 1;
        int dataCount = data.Count;
        for ( int dataIdx = 0 ; dataIdx < dataCount ; ++dataIdx )
        {
            T item = data [ dataIdx ];
            int column = 1;

            for ( int propIdx = 0 ; propIdx < props.Count ( ) ; ++propIdx )
            {
                PropertyInfo pi = props [ propIdx ];
                if ( !pi.Name.StartsWith ( "IGN_" ) )
                {
                    object value = item.GetType ( ).GetProperty ( pi.Name ).GetValue ( item, null );

                    if ( pi.PropertyType == typeof ( DateTime ) || pi.PropertyType == typeof ( DateTime? ) )
                        wsSheet.Cells [ startRow, column ].Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
                    else if ( pi.PropertyType == typeof ( bool ) || pi.PropertyType == typeof ( bool? ) )
                        value = ConvertBoolToString ( ( bool ) value );
                    else if ( value != null && ( pi.PropertyType == typeof ( decimal ) || pi.PropertyType == typeof ( decimal? ) ) )
                    {
                        decimal argument = ( decimal ) value;
                        int count = BitConverter.GetBytes ( decimal.GetBits ( argument ) [ 3 ] ) [ 2 ];
                        if ( count == 3 )
                            wsSheet.Cells [ startRow, column ].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00 €";
                        else
                            wsSheet.Cells [ startRow, column ].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00000 €";
                    }
                    else if ( pi.PropertyType == typeof ( string ) && value != null && ( ( string ) value ).StartsWith ( "REP_" ) )
                    {
                        string _value = value.ToString ( ).Replace ( "REP_", "" );
                        value = ResourceManagement.GetResourceValue ( ( string ) _value );
                    }
                    else if ( pi.Name == "Duration" && value != null )
                    {
                        value = ResourceManagement.GetResourceValue ( value.ToString ( ) );
                    }

                    wsSheet.Cells [ startRow, column ].Value = value;
                    column++;
                }
            }
            finalColumn = column;
            startRow++;
        }

        using ( var range = wsSheet.Cells [ 2, 1, data.Count ( ) + 1, finalColumn - 1 ] )
        {
            range.Style.Font.Bold = false;
            range.Style.Font.Size = 10;
            range.Style.ShrinkToFit = false;
            range.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            range.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor ( Color.White );
        }
    }
```

Note: I'm using Epplus for the Excel operations.

Comment: How long is it taking and over how my cells?  If it is a lot there may not be much you can do about.  You might save a little if you filter you props collection at the very start rather than constantly checking with something like this `var propsIgn = typeof (T).GetProperties().Where(pi => !pi.Name.StartsWith("IGN_")).ToList();` and then remove the if statement `if ( !pi.Name.StartsWith ( "IGN_" ) )`.  It may be trivial but worth a shot.  A `ForEach` wont make a different - cant really beat the speed of a true `for` loop.

Comment: Also, see if you can cache you data properties somehow.  The line `object value = item.GetType().GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(item, null);` might be costing you some since you are getting the `PropertyInfo` at O(m*n).